# azure architecture hybrid solution

Tags: azure, hybrid

I need build some sort of a proxy between an "on premise" webservice and a d365fo installation in Azure cloud.

The onPrem service is a DAM system, that keeps masterdata of product images, and PDF's etc. I do not wish to upload these to d365, but make a link from the d365 product to DAM. Access to the DAM system service is password protected, so I need a proxy between.

Initially I thought about building a web service and host it on an onPrem IIS, but now I am wondering if tis could be hosted in Azure?

The proxy should only be accessible in onPrem local network.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But in general, I think your question is too broad. We do answer specific technical questions on programming here. This is not a community that helps you *architecting* designing your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first things you want to look at is what element can/are you able to expose, as if you build something in Azure, that means your DAM system need to be reachable from outside to query it. If this is already the case then fine, otherwise its sometimes a security issue for compagnies to open their internal systems to the internet.

I think you are better off putting your "middleware"/proxy on prem, and you only need to make IIS reacheable from the IP range of your D365FO subscription.

From there you should be able to do what you need.

My only concern for this would be if the files are huge, that the transfert rate might be low if the files are hosted on prem versus Azure/FTP....

Good luck !